# pySpark hudi table partial updating with org.apache.hudi.common.model.PartialUpdateAvroPayload not working

Tags: pyspark, aws-glue, avro, apache-hudi

I have two tables in S3 tableA with columns id, col1, col2 and col3. tableB with columns id, col4 and col5.
I want to write this data into another s3 in Hudi format as tableC with columns id, col1, col2, col3, col4, col5.

I do not want to join the data frames because in my real time use case i will receive incremental data and may not always have matching records available in both tables, so i am trying to implement org.apache.hudi.common.model.PartialUpdateAvroPayload option.

Below is the script I run for the first time where it inserts tableA records first, by adding empty value to col4 and col5 of tableB for the initial table creation and it works fine.

```
tablea_df = (spark.read 
       .format("hudi")
       .load(s3_path_tablea))

additional_options = {
    "hoodie.table.name": "hudiTableAplusB",
    "hoodie.datasource.write.table.type": "COPY_ON_WRITE",
    "hoodie.datasource.write.operation": "upsert",
    "hoodie.datasource.write.recordkey.field": "id",
    "hoodie.datasource.write.precombine.field": "id",
    "hoodie.datasource.write.hive_style_partitioning": "true",
    "hoodie.parquet.compression.codec": "gzip",
    "hoodie.datasource.write.payload.class": "org.apache.hudi.common.model.PartialUpdateAvroPayload",
    "hoodie.datasource.write.reconcile.schema": "true",
    "hoodie.bloom.index.update.partition.path": "false",
}
tablea_df = tablea_df.withColumn("col4", lit('').cast(StringType()))
tablea_df = tablea_df.withColumn("col5", lit('').cast(StringType()))

tablea_df.write.format("hudi").options(
    **additional_options
).mode("append").save(
    s3_path_curated
)

tableb_df = (spark.read 
       .format("hudi")
       .load(s3_path_tableb))

additional_options = {
    "hoodie.table.name": "hudiTableAplusB",
    "hoodie.datasource.write.table.type": "COPY_ON_WRITE",
    "hoodie.datasource.write.operation": "upsert",
    "hoodie.datasource.write.recordkey.field": "id",
    "hoodie.datasource.write.precombine.field": "id",
    "hoodie.datasource.write.hive_style_partitioning": "true",
    "hoodie.parquet.compression.codec": "gzip",
    "hoodie.datasource.write.payload.class": "org.apache.hudi.common.model.PartialUpdateAvroPayload",
    "hoodie.datasource.write.reconcile.schema": "true",
    "hoodie.bloom.index.update.partition.path": "false",
}
tableb_df.write.format("hudi").options(
    **additional_options
).mode("append").save(
    s3_path_curated
)
```

For the second time I don't want to add empty values to col4 and col5 as I want to retain the existing value. I removed the below lines form above code and try to apply a partial payload upsert.

```
tablea_df = tablea_df.withColumn("col4", lit('').cast(StringType()))
tablea_df = tablea_df.withColumn("col5", lit('').cast(StringType()))
```

I get the below error

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null of string in field col4 of hoodie.hudiTableAplusB.hudiTableAplusB_record

Note: Strange part is for the second time if I run partial upsert reading the data from tableB only, by removing the tableA write logic it works fine! But dosent work for TableA.

Using following jar files Hudi Jar: hudi-spark3.3-bundle_2.12-0.14.0.jar, Spark Avro: spark-avro_2.13-3.3.0.jar